# While loop issue in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a while loop, I am trying to have a user enter a number from 1 to 50 and display the numbers.  What I have so far prints out a message if I am within 50 and prints another message if I am over 50 but I need it to continue if the user wants to enter another number but it just exits.

Below is what I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int from = 1;
        const int to = 50;

        int randomNumber = 50;
        int enteredNumber;

        Console.Write("The number is between 1 and 50.", from, to);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enteredNumber))
            {
                if (enteredNumber <= randomNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a number between 1 & 50");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (enteredNumber > randomNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a number between 1 & 50.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Have you stepped through in the debugger?

Comment: randomNumber = 50? I feel an XKCD coming on.... http://www.xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Don't break the while loop and it will continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted the `break` is in the wrong location.

Take a look at this. I cleaned it up and added some error handling and now allow the user to quit by entering "**Quit**" or continue by pressing "**Enter**".

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int from = 1;
        const int to = 50;

        int randomNumber = 50;
        int enteredNumber;

        Console.Write("The number is between 1 and 50.", from, to);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enteredNumber))
            {
                if (enteredNumber <= randomNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a number between 1 & 50. Hit 'Enter' play again or enter 'Quit' to exit");
                    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (answer.ToLower() == "quit")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (enteredNumber > randomNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a number between 1 & 50. Hit 'Enter' play again or enter 'Quit' to exit");
                    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (answer.ToLower() == "quit")
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a number between 1 & 50. Hit 'Enter' play again or enter 'Quit' to exit");
                var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.ToLower() == "quit")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the break it exits the while loop.

Place the break under:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Sure thing :) Could you also accept this as the answer? So your problem is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer(s) you can use the `continue` keyword if you want to exit execution of the current iteration and move to the next iteration:

e.g.

```
while(true)
{
    if(somecondition)
      continue; // <-- this line will cause execution to move to the next iteration, skipping the code below it

    dosomethingelse();
}
```